# get all subfolders from a public network shared drive

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get all the names of the folder from a public drive shared on the network. It is very simple i know but i think the server path is wrong i tried using various variations for path but it does not work.

Here is an images of the drive to the folder .
[image: Image 1][image: Image 2][image: Image 3][image: Image 4]

my controller

```
public ActionResult GetFolders()
    {
        string path = Server.MapPath("\\\\NC2PWSHV1\\Users");
        List<string> picFolders = new List<string>();

        foreach (string dir in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
        {
            picFolders.Add(dir);
        }

        return View(picFolders);
    }
```

my view

```
@model IEnumerable<string>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "GetFolders";
}

<h2>GetFolders</h2>

<table>
<tbody>
    @foreach (string picFolders in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @picFolders
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an MS article which will do what you need here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-enumerate-directories-and-files

The main bit you need is:

```
        string dirPath = @"\\archives\2009\reports";

        List<string> dirs = new List<string>(Directory.EnumerateDirectories(dirPath));
```